# How can you tell when Eth 2.0 Test-net will be finished

Tags: testnets, eth-2.0

is there a way to tell when the test net will be completed?

Feel free to call me ignorant in ur response ahahahah

Comment: What do you mean by "finished"? Eth 2.0 doesn't exists as such, the changes will be an upgrade to existing networks: mainnet, ropsten, rinkeby, goerli, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Users and operators of those testnets usually come to some plan or goals. In the end, they choose when to stop using them.

You can find a good post about some of these conclusions for various existing testnets here: https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/og-council-post-merge-testnets/9034

If you want to keep using a testnet after it has been abandonned by everyone else, you still can. Simply spin up a few nodes and keep securing it.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for clarifying! The test net officially ended at 9pm est yesterday though.

Comment: I understand it doesn't have an official end - it being decentralized and all but why and how did It pass the final faze if theres no official end?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *final faze*?